# How to enable input fields depending on mat-select options>?

Tags: html, typescript, mat-select, mat-form-field

Inside a `mat-tab` I have a form which contains a `mat-select` with the following code:

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
     <mat-label>Database</mat-label>
          <mat-select [formControl]="types" multiple>
                    <mat-select-trigger>
                         {{(types?.value ||[''])[0]}}
                           <span *ngIf="(types.value?.length || 0) > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
                                        (+{{(types.value?.length || 0) - 1}} {{types.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' :
                                        'others'}})
                           </span>
                      </mat-select-trigger>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let type of typeList" [value]="type">{{type}}</mat-option>
           </mat-select>
      <mat-icon matSuffix>storage</mat-icon>
   </mat-form-field>
```

The options available in mat-select on typescript are:

```
  types = new FormControl('');
  typeList: string[] = ['SQLite', 'Microsoft SQL Server', 'MySQL'];
```

Below mat-select, I have some input fields inserted in `mat-accordion`

```
                  <mat-accordion>
                        <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
                            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                <mat-panel-title> SQLite Database </mat-panel-title>
                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
                                <mat-label>Database Name</mat-label>
                                <input [disabled]="!types.value[0]" id="numeDB_SQLite" type="text" matInput
                                    placeholder="Ex: Lite_DB" name="numeDB_SQLite" ngModel required=""
                                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter DB name')"
                                    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                            </mat-form-field>
                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
                                <mat-label>Database string Connection</mat-label>
                                <input [disabled]="!types.value[0]" id="stringConnDB_SQLite" type="text" matInput
                                    placeholder="Ex: " name="stringConnDB_SQLite" ngModel required=""
                                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter DB connection string')"
                                    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </mat-expansion-panel>
                    </mat-accordion>
                    <br />
                    <mat-accordion>
                        <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState2 = true" (closed)="panelOpenState2 = false">
                            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                <mat-panel-title> Microsoft SQL Server Database </mat-panel-title>
                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
                                <mat-label>Database Name</mat-label>
                                <input [disabled]="!types.value[1]" id="numeDB_MSSQL" type="text" matInput
                                    placeholder="Ex: MSSQL_DB" name="numeDB_MSSQL" ngModel required=""
                                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter DB name')"
                                    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                            </mat-form-field>
                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
                                <mat-label>Database string Connection</mat-label>
                                <input [disabled]="!types.value[1]" id="stringConnDB_MSSQL" type="text" matInput
                                    placeholder="Ex: " name="stringConnDB_MSSQL" ngModel required=""
                                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter DB connection string')"
                                    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </mat-expansion-panel>
                    </mat-accordion>
                    <br />
                    <mat-accordion>
                        <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState1 = true" (closed)="panelOpenState1 = false">
                            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                <mat-panel-title> MySQL Database </mat-panel-title>
                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
                                <mat-label>Database Name</mat-label>
                                <input [disabled]="!types.value[2]" id="numeDB_MySQL" type="text" matInput
                                    placeholder="Ex: MySQL_DB" name="numeDB_MySQL" ngModel required=""
                                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter DB name')"
                                    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                            </mat-form-field>
                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
                                <mat-label>Database string Connection</mat-label>
                                <input [disabled]="!types.value[2]" id="stringConnDB_MySQL" type="text" matInput
                                    placeholder="Ex: " name="stringConnDB_MySQL" ngModel required=""
                                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter DB connection string')"
                                    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </mat-expansion-panel>
                    </mat-accordion>
```

What I want to do is to enable the inputs associated with the option selected from  mat-select. If the option is deselected, the input fields should be disabled. It works but not completely OK. On init, all input fields are disabled.

If I select the mat-select's options in this order: SQLite, Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL; the input fields are enabled in the same order as options have been selected.

If mat-select's options are selected in order: Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL; first are enabled the inputs associated with SQLite and when the MySQL is selected, the Microsoft SQL Server's fields are enabled.

If I select only the third option (MySQL), SQLite's input fields are enabled and not MySQL's input fields as it should be working.
What am I doing wrong?